# Picker inside of form no longer selecting

Tags: swift, swiftui, picker

I have a picker inside of a form. Previously it was selecting the items correctly, however, after changing the code to fix another issue it no longer works. The items the picker is using is fetched from coredata. How can I fix this issue?

```
@FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: [])
var sources: FetchedResults<Source>
@State private var selectedSource = 0
```

Here is the code I am using for the picker.

```
Picker(selection: $selectedSource, label: Text("Source")) {
    ForEach(sources, id: \.self) { source in
        Text(source.name!)
            .tag(source)
    }
}
```

Here is a link to a video of the issue. [Video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tSFD5.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type that you provide in `Picker(selection:)` (which is currently `Int` -- `selectedSource`) needs to be the same as the type that you provide in `tag()`, which is currently `Source`.

You could, for example, use the ID of `Source` (I'm assuming it has one) as your `selectedSource` and then use the same IDs in your `tag()`

Comment: Thanks! I used `@State private var selectedSource: Source?` and `Text(source.name!).tag(source as Source?)` to get it working.